# How to change sampling rate for android's MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am wondering if there is a way to change the sampling rate at which MediaPlayer plays data back.  I'd like to tweak it and play data back at a slower rate than encoded.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be doable with MediaPlayer, but for audio you can do it with [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html):

> The playback rate can also be changed. A playback rate of 1.0 causes
>   the sound to play at its original frequency (resampled, if necessary,
>   to the hardware output frequency). A playback rate of 2.0 causes the
>   sound to play at twice its original frequency, and a playback rate of
>   0.5 causes it to play at half its original frequency. The playback rate range is 0.5 to 2.0.

You didn't mention this in your original question, but if you want to maintain pitch while changing the frequency, you'd need to provide a pitch-shift algorithm.  Perhaps there's one in the [android.media.audiofx](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/package-summary.html) package - there's a [queryEffects()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#queryEffects%28%29) method that might return some type of pitch shifter.

For MediaPlayer, you might look at the [attachAuxEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#attachAuxEffect%28int%29) method that would let you process the audio stream.